# Observer function auto call twice in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, event-observer

I have created one function in Observer and set it called on product save after via config.xml file events section.

When I press "save & edit continue", this function log all the information twice.

What is the reason, why this happened?

**Config.xml file code:**

```
<global>
     <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <blogapi>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>testapi/observer</class>
                    <method>postProductAsPost</method>
                </blogapi>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

**Observer.php file code:**

```
<?php
class Custom_Testapi_Model_Observer
{
    const API_URL = "http://localhost/testsite/api/index.php/posts";

    public function postProductAsPost(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        $postResponse = array();
        $post_id = $name = $title = $conditionType = $condition = $productUrl = $imgUrl = $capacity = $sku = $shortDesc = $otherInfo = $postContent = '';
        $metaInfo = $categories = array();
        $updateImage = false;
        $price = '';


        if(!empty($product) && $product->getIsOption() != 1)
        {
            $sku = trim($product->getSku());
            $shortDesc = strtoupper(trim($product->getShortDescription()));
            $name = trim($product->getName());
            $machineUrl = trim(Mage::getBaseUrl().$product->getUrlPath());
            $imgUrl =(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(500);
            $capacity = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('capacity')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
            $condition =  trim($product->getCondition());
     
            $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
            foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
                $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
                $categories[] = $_cat->getName();
            }
            $metaTitle = trim($product->getMetaTitle());
            $metaKeywords = trim($product->getMetaKeyword());
            $metaDesc = trim($product->getMetaDescription());
            $metaInfo = array('title' =>$metaTitle,'keywords'=>$metaKeywords,'description'=>$metaDesc);

            $title = strtoupper(trim($capacity.$condition." ".$name));

            if(!empty($shortDesc))
            {
                $postContent .= '<p>'.$shortDesc.'</p>';
            }

            if($product->getPrice() > 0 && $product->getPrice() != '')
            {
                $price = Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(), true, false);
            }
            else
            {
                $price = "Call for price";
            }

            if($price != '')
            {
                $postContent .= '<p> Cost: '.$price.'</p>';
            }

            if(!empty($machineUrl))
            {
                $postContent .= '<p><a href="'.$productUrl.'" title="productUrl">'.$productUrl.'</a></p>';
            }

            $postDatas = array(
                'title' => $title,
                'categories' => $categories,
                'machine_url' => $machineUrl,
                'short_description' => $shortDesc,
                'image_url' => $imgUrl,
                'other_info' => $otherInfo,
                'blog_post_content' => $postContent,
                'meta_info'=>$metaInfo
            );

            /*if($post_id != '')
            {
                array_merge($postDatas,array('post_id'=>$post_id));
            }*/

            try {
                $url = self::API_URL;

                $curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();

                $curl->setConfig(array('timeout' => 0));
                $headers= array('Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Basic username:password');
                $curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST, $url, '1.0', $headers, json_encode($postDatas));
                $res = $curl->read();
                $response = '';

                $httpCode = Zend_Http_Response::extractCode($res);
                $response = Zend_Http_Response::extractBody($res);
                $curl->close();

                if ($httpCode == 200) //if success
                {
                    
                    if (!empty($response)) {

                        Mage::log("Response -- " . print_r($response, true), null, 'blog.log', true);

                    }

                }

            }catch (Exception $e)
            {
                Mage::log("Error Msg -- " . $e->getMessage(), null, 'blog.log', true);
            }

            return;

        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you share observer.php file

Comment: Maybe you call it twice. Share your code so we can see what's happening.

Comment: yes exactly @marius you are right, we cant assume anything without having a look at the code

Comment: @Marius and Chikku,  I have updated the question, kindly take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save and edit maybe triggers the product save twice.
there's the same behavior saving it without continue?

you've tryed even using catalog_product_save_before event?

One thing you can do is to set a Flag in the execution so that he wont do your logic twice:

```
    if(Mage::registry('catalog_product_save_after_observer_executed')){
        return $this; //this method has already been executed once in this request
    }

    ...

    Mage::register('catalog_product_save_after_observer_executed',true);
```